# Event for pages when they get selected in a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to find a good way of calling a method of the page being selected in a TabControl. Here's what I'm working with:

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabC" SelectionChanged="TabC_SelectionChanged">
            <TabItem Header="Home" x:Name="HomeTab" IsSelected="True">
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <Frame Source="HomePage.xaml"/>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Test" x:Name="TestTab">
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <Frame Source="TestPage.xaml"/>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Test1" x:Name="Test1Tab">
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <Frame Source="Test1Page.xaml"/>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

So on my Homepage.xaml.cs, for example, I want a method to be called when I click the tabitem corresponding to it's page. How would you do this?
Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `OnLoaded` event in each of your user controls.

The `OnLoaded` event fires each time you switch tabs.

---

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication.HomePage" Loaded="HomePage_OnLoaded" ... >
```

Code-behind:

```
private void HomePage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Something to do each time the tab is clicked and the page is "loaded"
}
```